# PHP: Undefined offset: 0, but not with dd()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting an `Undefined offset: 0` error with laravel. The strange  thing is that when I `dd()` it, it shows up.

```
  $ports = $container->getPorts();
  $ports = $ports[0];
```

This returns `Undefined offset: 0`

When I `dd()`

```
$ports = $container->getPorts();
dd($ports[0]);

Port {#336 
  #privatePort: 80
  #publicPort: 32780
  #type: "tcp"
}
```

The full array:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => Port {#336 ▼
    #privatePort: 80
    #publicPort: 32780
    #type: "tcp"
  }
]
```

I am getting this error with the docker-php sdk. Anyone that has a clue about what is going on?

Full code:

```
public function dockerContainers()
{
    $docker = new \Docker\Docker();
    $containerManager = $docker->getContainerManager();
    $containers = $containerManager->findAll();

    $data = [];
    $x=0;
    foreach ($containers as $container) {
        $ports = $container->getPorts();
        // dd($ports[0]);
        $ports = $ports[0];
        $privatePort = $ports->getPrivatePort();
        $publicPort = $ports->getPublicPort();
        $data[$x++] = [
            'id'    => $container->getId(),
            'state'  => $container->getState(),
            'names'  => $container->getNames(),
            'image'  => $container->getImage(),
            'status' => $container->getStatus(),
            'ports'  => [
                'privatePort' => $privatePort,
                'publicPort'  => $publicPort
            ]
        ];
    }

    return view('containers', [ 'containers' => $data ]);
}
```

Comment: What is the full error message?  Is the Undefined offset: 0 related to $ports or $data?

Comment: It is related to $ports. I tried a foreach over $ports to get the values and put them in an array. This does work, and suits my case. But I am still wondering why this happens.

Comment: did you try $port = $ports[0];?

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro Yes, it produces the same error.

Comment: what do you get if you execute `$ports = array_shift($ports);` ?

Comment: @aaron0207 This actually works.

Comment: please dump $ports[0] on foreach , i think
one of the containers get ports return null

Comment: Is this code being run via the command line?

Answer (score 0):

This is because one of your `container` does not have `ports` it is good practice to use laravel [collect()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods) method which makes your array into collection object and then you can use available collection methods.
Try the following code...

```html
    foreach ($containers as $container) {
            //getting ports and making laravel collection object
        $ports = collect($container->getPorts());
       if($ports->first()){
        $ports = $ports->first();
        $privatePort = $ports->getPrivatePort();
        $publicPort = $ports->getPublicPort();
        $data[$x++] = [
            'id'    => $container->getId(),
            'state'  => $container->getState(),
            'names'  => $container->getNames(),
            'image'  => $container->getImage(),
            'status' => $container->getStatus(),
            'ports'  => [
                'privatePort' => $privatePort,
                'publicPort'  => $publicPort
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: It has been a long time since I posted this question. If I do recall it right, a container without ports is impossible in this case. Thanks for the `collect()` tip. I will be working on this project again in a couple of weeks. I will keep this thread updated if I can test it again.